# How can i scroll images dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I m pretty new to iPhone development. I'm trying to implement scroll view with loading images dynamically from web. I m trying to use the following code.

```
 for (counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:counter];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: entry.articleUrl]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    NSLog(@"%@", entry.articleUrl);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [imageData release];
    CGRect rect = scrollViewController.frame;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = (counter + 1);  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [scrollViewController addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

These are two images that I load up on `viewDidLoad`. I want to load the next image when the user scroll onto the second image and if the user scroll next want to show that the image is loading. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You muse use NSURLConnection and download the images asynchronously. You can use TCImageView

https://github.com/totocaster/TCImageView

It downloads the images in an async way.

I would also recommend Three20's TTImageView.

Comment: `TCImageView` was just updated and renamed to `TCWebImageView`: https://github.com/totocaster/TCWebImageView